# How to combine/merge multiple queries in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, merge

I cannot find similar question related specially to my case. So I post this question. And also ne need to provide sample data because below informations are enough.

My matches table is:

| home_team_id | away_team_id | htft |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11 | 9 | 2/2 |
| 18 | 17 | X/2 |
| 20 | 19 | 2/2 |
| 1 | 8 | X/2 |
| 4 | 12 | 1/X |
| 14 | 2 | 2/2 |
| 3 | 16 | 1/1 |
| 13 | 15 | 2/X |
| 7 | 10 | 1/1 |
| 5 | 6 | 1/1 |
| 9 | 13 | 1/1 |

and teams table is:

| team_id | team_name |
| --- | --- |
| 5 | Arsenal |
| 6 | Aston Villa |
| 7 | Brentford |
| 8 | Brighton & Hove Albion |
| 9 | Burnley |
| 12 | Chelsea |
| 19 | Crystal Palace |
| 18 | Everton |
| 20 | Leeds United |
| 31 | Leicester City |
| 32 | Liverpool |

I have 2 queries. One is show home matches count and second one is away team count results. There are working fine.
But how can I merge these two queries at one query?

My tables structures are;

**teams** table fields: ***team_id, team_name***

**matches** table fields:  ***home_team_id, away.team_id, htft***

**Home Query:**

```
  SELECT m.home_team_id,t.team_name as Home,
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'X/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'X/X',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2/2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'X/2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1/X',      
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2/X',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1/2'

    FROM matches m, teams t
    where m.home_team_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY m.home_team_id;
```

Output:

| home_team_id | Home | 1/1 | X/1 | X/X | 2/2 | X/2 | 1/X | 2/X | 2/1 | 1/2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | Arsenal | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 7 | Brentford | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | Burnley | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 18 | Everton | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 20 | Leeds United | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

**Away Query:**

```
  SELECT m.away_team_id,t.team_name as Away,
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'X/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'X/X',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2/2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = 'X/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'X/2',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1/X',      
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/X' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2/X',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '2/1' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '2/1',
         SUM(CASE WHEN m.htft = '1/2' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS '1/2'

    FROM matches m, teams t
    where m.away_team_id = t.team_id
GROUP BY m.away_team_id;
```

Output:

| away_team_id | Away | 1/1 | X/1 | X/X | 2/2 | X/2 | 1/X | 2/X | 2/1 | 1/2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | Aston Villa | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 8 | Brighton & Hove Albion | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 9 | Burnley | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 12 | Chelsea | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 19 | Crystal Palace | 0 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

How can I merge or combine both queries. I think if both queries possible to merge it will give the result I expected.

Thanks in advance to those who will help.

**Expected result :**

| Team | HTFT(1/1) | HTFT(X/1) | HTFT(X/X) | HTFT(2/2) | HTFT(X/2) | HTFT(1/X) | HTFT(2/X) | HTFT(2/1) | HTFT(1/2) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Arsenal | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Aston Villa | 0 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 |
| Everton | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 2 | 1 |

---

**Current Home results Query**
[image]

**Current Away results Query**
[image]

Comment: Could you add an example of what you want the "merged" output to look like?

Comment: At the bottom of my question I added the expected results (what I need) as tables as you requested. I hope it helps.

Comment: I have added the output for each of your queries based on the sample data provided in your question. How do you get from those two tables to the "Required result" you have provided?

Comment: @cimmy use [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50dc46d00c5437e893de9bce47c6a545) for better explanation

Comment: Hi nnichols, updated. ht and ft removed. Only I need HTFT column totals by team.

Comment: @Ergest Basha created fiddle is correct.What I mentioned above requested. So I need both query can be work as one query?

Comment: @nnichols
I added Home and Away MySQL Workbench results as image bottom of my question. . You my check exact results.

Comment: Please do not post images of result sets and / or data! Update your expected results table based on the sample source data you provided.

Comment: @nnichols It's impossible to posting my result data and(or sample it is 1465 rows. Thats why I uploaded screen shots. I think all are clear in my question. Why you requested still data.? If it is not clear for you you don't need to check this question except solution. Thanks.

Comment: [Fiddle Sample Data Here !](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=50dc46d00c5437e893de9bce47c6a545) 
Ergest Basha is already designed instead of my sample in fiddle. You can check it.

Comment: I only need how to merge provided query. I gave sample data, tables details and data, home and away query with text. And also I added screen shots what I have currently in my hand. So if possible just merge both queries in one query only.  First and Second tables are my sample data already. What you expected more? Thanks..

Comment: This is my last attempt! The only team appearing in both result sets (based on sample data provided) currently is Burnley and it is not even represented in your expected result. If you cannot understand why that makes your expected results example useless, then I am not sure how to help you. If you cannot even demonstrate what you want to achieve, how are we supposed to help you achieve it?

Comment: I prepered fiddle sample databse for you. Pls. check on confirm. [My fiddle link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=81f6811d831046a7194c392ce1918672)